# To display the data when passing the data using putExtra

Tags: java, android, android-intent

The thing is i want to passing the data from an activity to another activity. For example, at first this apps i have to log in then it will go to main activity. If I log in, didnt log out and close the apps, the apps will stay at the main activity but if the user logout and exit, the user when open it, it will go to login activity. The things is I login the editview such as username then at the intent the data i use putExtra to passing to another activity. Then at the another activity i getExtra the data and I want to display it. It is working fine but the thing is when I close the apps then open again it will not responding because the passing data from an activity to another activity. Maybe because it is null n no data to send to another activity. So the prob is I want to know how to prevent this and what can i do to solve this prob? Tq for read my prob n please give suggestions to solve this prob. TQ

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your code.

Comment: save the passed data to a local variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you are looking for, can be done easily by using [SharedPref](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) in android.

Take a look on this tutorial- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0):

http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-shared-preferences-in-android/28370

please refer this link, hope this can be useful for your problem.